# selecting multiple columns from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

below is my query

```
select p.problem_id,
       p.problem_title,
       p.description,
       paps.problem_external_source_id, 
       paps.problem_and_problem_source_id 
  from problem_backup p,
       problem_and_problem_source paps 
 where p.problem_id=paps.problem_id and paps.free_user_id!='null';
```

My question is how to select another table columns based on the retrieved columns(i.e in my query i want to select some more columns from another table based on problem_and_problem_source_id) that is retrieved ,i want to do it in the same query,can we do the whole work in procedures..

Comment: which table's column do you want to display and what is the join criteria

Comment: Yep, as sashi said you're looking for what's called a "join" which temporarily combines two tables (by matching a column from one table to another) what do your tables look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the another table in same way. Notice `paps.free_user_id!='null'` should be `paps.free_user_id is not null`, only except if you means the user_id is really string `'null'`.

```
select p.problem_id,
       p.problem_title,
       p.description,
       paps.problem_external_source_id, 
       paps.problem_and_problem_source_id,
       yat.*
from problem_backup p
inner join problem_and_problem_source paps
  on  p.problem_id = paps.problem_id
inner join your_another_table yat
  on paps.problem_and_problem_source_id = yat.join_column_name
where  paps.free_user_id is not null
```

Comment: can we go all this stuff with stored procedures

Comment: If you mean can this query be used inside a stored procedure then yes. If you mean can you use a stored procedure to perform the same function as a join, why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: thanks for replying Braiba,which is the best way....i want to use this query in stored procedure